# How do I target two slides prior to the active slide in swiper/react library?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, swiper.js

If this is the code:

```
 //current

  :global(.swiper-slide-active) { 
    transform: scaleY(1.05) translateY(10px);
  }

  //next 

  :global(.swiper-slide-next) {
    opacity: 80%;
  }

  //second next

  :global(.swiper-slide-next + .swiper-slide) {
    opacity: 40%;
  }

  //previous 

  :global(.swiper-slide-prev) {
    opacity: 80%;
  }
  //second previous ???
```

As you can see, I successfully managed to reach the first previous slide and all other ones after the active slide, but I do have trouble trying to style slides prior to the first previous slide using adjacent sibling combinator. Any suggestions on how to approach this?